# Таймер с повторением действия каждую секунду не работает

Tags: c#

Я новичок в C# немогли бы вы мне помочь исправить код. Что бы действие повторялось каждую секунду. Т.е вылезал message box каждую секунду.

```
void StartTimer()
        {
            int timeout = 0;

            while (true)
            {
                timeout = (1 - DateTime.Now.Second) * 1 - DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
                Thread.Sleep(timeout);

                MessageBox.Show("Nen");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вызов `MessageBox.Show("...")` останавливает текущее выполнение кода (текущий поток) до тех пор, пока пользователь его не закроет. Поэтому ваш код работать не будет. Для осуществления задуманного вам надо использовать **многопоточность** или **таймер**, который сделает это за вас. Поэтому советую отложить задуманное, пока не дойдете до этих тем.

Comment: Лучше начинать изучение с консольных приложений, так как там меньше заморочек.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {

       private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          SetTimer();

          Console.ReadLine();
          aTimer.Stop();
          aTimer.Dispose();
       }

       private static void SetTimer()
       {
            // Таймер с интервалом в секунду
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
            // Событие когда таймер идет 
            aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            aTimer.AutoReset = true;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.SignalTime);
            //TODO
        }
    }
}
```

проверить можете [тут](https://rextester.com/EPV19796)

Comment: ошибку выдает когда я это добавил в свой код . В это строчке public static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: Ошибка CS0017 Для программы определено несколько точек входа. Компиляция с /main позволит указать тип, содержащий точку входа. Themoon C:\Users\Themoon\Themoon\Form1.cs 55 Н/Д

Comment: @АндрейReyz добавьте в свой код функции `SetTimer()` и `OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)`. Потом в `OnTimedEvent` запишите что вам нужно выполнять по истичению секунды. И вызовите таймер с помощью `SetTimer();` там где вам нужно...например в `Form_Load()`

Comment: измените свой пример тогда.

Comment: @АндрейReyz что в моем примере не так?? вы пытаетесь `Main` впихнуть в `WinForm`.... по моему я тут никак не виноват

Comment: а во все заработало